# Makefile for program running on different machines

Tags: bash, makefile, nfs, host

I have a C++ program that will run on several machines that use a Network File System. For each of the C++ libraries that my program uses, I installed a version for each machine, under ~/program_files/machinename/libraryname.

"machinename" is obtained via bash command "hostname". On the machines I am using, "hostname" outputs something like "io21.aaa.bbb.edu" and I take only "io21" as "machinename" for the path to the libraries. In bash, I learned that

> $ HOST=`hostname` # now the value of HOST is "io21.aaa.bbb.edu"
>
> $ HOST=${HOST%%.*} # extract "io21" from "io21.aaa.bbb.edu"
>
> $ echo ${HOST}
>
> io21

In the Makefile of my program, I want to call these bash commands to specify the path to the library according to the current machine:

> HOST := $(shell hostname)
>
> HOST := $(shell ${HOST%%.*})
>
> LDFLAGS=-L${HOME}/program_files/${HOST}/libraryname/lib
>
> CXXFLAGS=-Wall -I${HOME}/program_files/${HOST}/libraryname/include

The first line is working i.e. HOST is "io21.aaa.bbb.edu", but the second line which extracts "io21" doesn't work and HOST is still "io21.aaa.bbb.edu".

I am wondering how I should solve this problem?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively you can use

```
HOST := $(shell echo $(HOST) | cut -d . -f 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
HOST := $(shell hostname)
HOST := $(shell host=$(HOST);echo $${host%%.*})
```

`make` defaults to `/bin/sh` which may not support the `$(var%%string)` construct depending on which version you have. Also, mixing `make` variables and `bash` variables is a bit challenging.